# Iterate over spark cogroup() pairrdd output in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I created 2 Pair RDD's in Spark

```
var pairrdd = sc.parallelize(List((1,2),(3,4),(3,6)))
var pairrdd2 = sc.parallelize(List((3,9)))
```

I applied the cogroup function

```
var cogrouped = pairrdd.cogroup(pairrdd2)
```

The object type for cogroupedrdd looks like below.

```
cogrouped: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, (Iterable[Int], Iterable[Int]))] = MapPartitionsRDD[801] at cogroup at <console>:60
```

I am trying to create a function to iterate over these values

```
def iterateThis((x: Int,(x1:Iterable[Int],x2:Iterable[Int])))={
  println(x1.mkString(","))
}
```

but am I getting below error.

```
<console>:21: error: identifier expected but '(' found.
       def iterateThis((x: Int,(x1:Iterable[Int],x2:Iterable[Int])))={
                   ^
```

Comment: How to use `cogroup` for large datasets like when I use `collect()` it throws out of memory exception `rdd1 = rdd2.cogroup(rdd3).collect`. Can you help on this issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180307/how-to-use-cogroup-for-large-datasets]. can partitioning help I'm new to spark any help to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is of type `(Int, (Iterable[Int], Iterable[Int]))`:

```
def iterateThis(arg: (Int, (Iterable[Int], Iterable[Int]))) = {
  val (_, (x1, _)) = arg
  println(x1.mkString(","))
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this supersonic response, Could you please elaborate as to why this is wrong def iterateThis((x: Int,(x1:Iterable[Int],x2:Iterable[Int])))